# Transparent Border In CSS

Tags: css, transparent

Recently I am creating a website. I want to make a transparent border around the main title CSS.

**Code:

````
h1
{
    background-color: rgb(66, 113, 214);
    color:#581845;
}```

Can Anyone help me?
Thank you
````

Answer (score 1):

If you want a transparent border you must change the `background-clip` property as, otherwise, the background color will show through.

Here I have added an `outline` so you can see the "gap" where the border is.

```css
h1 {
  background-color: rgb(66, 113, 214);
  color: #581845;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: .5em 1em;
  border: 12px solid transparent;
  outline: 1px solid red;
}

.clip {
  background-clip: content-box;
}

body {
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="clip">With Clipping</h1>

<h1>Without Clipping</h1>
```